# How to set visibility in react typescript on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, dom-events

I am creating a cookie consent in a react app where users can accept or reject. If the user has already accepted the cookie concept, dont show again.

I want to check on page load if the item is already set, don't display consent else display(html to hidden). But the issue is that onLoad event, the document is not ready. **How can I fix this?**

Also, I discovered that on page load is hitting the "OnpageLoad()"

**Accept** and **Reject** working fine

cookieconsent.ts

```
const storageType = localStorage;
const consentPropertyName = "jdc_consent";

const saveToStorage = () => storageType.setItem(consentPropertyName, "true");

class UserConsent {
  OnpageLoad() {
    debugger;
    const shouldShowPopUp = storageType.getItem(consentPropertyName);

    if (shouldShowPopUp != "true") {
      let html = document.getElementById("consent-pop") as HTMLElement;
      html.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  }

  async acceptConsent() {
    debugger;
    saveToStorage();
    let html = document.getElementById("consent-pop") as HTMLElement;
    html.classList.add("hidden");
    //html.style.display === "block";
  }

  async rejectConcent() {
    storageType.removeItem(consentPropertyName);
    let html = document.getElementById("consent-pop") as HTMLElement;
    html.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}

export default new UserConsent();
```

view.tsx

```
  <div>
    <div>
     ...
    </div>

      <div
        id="consent-pop"
        onLoad={cookieconsent.OnpageLoad}
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: "0",
        }}
        className="visible"
      >
        <p>
          By using this site you agree to our Terms and Conditions{" "}
          <a onClick={cookieconsent.acceptConsent}>Accept</a> or{" "}
          <a onClick={cookieconsent.rejectConcent}>Reject</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can try with attribute `hidden` or simpe style  `display:none `.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all that, but the problem is that on page load the dom is not ready. ```document.getElementById("consent-pop") as HTMLElement;``` is returning null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const storageType = localStorage;
const consentPropertyName = "jdc_consent";
const saveToStorage = () => storageType.setItem(consentPropertyName, "true");

class UserConsent {

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
  }

  handleLoad() {
    debugger;
    const shouldShowPopUp = storageType.getItem(consentPropertyName);

    if (shouldShowPopUp != "true") {
      let html = document.getElementById("consent-pop") as HTMLElement;
      html.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  }

  async acceptConsent() {
    debugger;
    saveToStorage();
    let html = document.getElementById("consent-pop") as HTMLElement;
    html.classList.add("hidden");
    //html.style.display === "block";
  }

  async rejectConcent() {
    storageType.removeItem(consentPropertyName);
    let html = document.getElementById("consent-pop") as HTMLElement;
    html.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}

export default new UserConsent();
```

Maybe like alternative try with `useEffect` also.